# The service worker does not call cached files when offline

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I cached the offline.html and image files using a service worker. Navigating to offline.html works fine. But it fails to load image from offline.html. At offline.html, it tries to get the image cached by the service worker directly without fetching it, but it fails because the internet is disconnected.

I tried changing the `cache.match('/offline.html')` part to `cache.match(event.request)`, but this does not move to offline.html. How do I configure the cached files to be used in offline.html when the Internet is disconnected?

```
// service-worker.js
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline";

const ASSETS = ["offline.html", "image/icon_replay_b_15pt.png"];

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
            cache.addAll(ASSETS);
        })()
    );
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            if ("navigationPreload" in self.registration) {
                await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
            }
        })()
    );

    self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
        console.log(event.request.url);
        event.respondWith(
            (async () => {
                try {
                    const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
                    if (preloadResponse) {
                        return preloadResponse;
                    }

                    const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
                    return networkResponse;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);

                    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
                    return cache.match("/offline.html");
                }
            })()
        );
    }
});
```

```
<!-- offline.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OFFLINE</title>
    <style>


        body { font-family:'NanumSquare'; }
        body, html {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; }
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
 
        .btn-outline-01 {
            border:1px solid #C9CACA;
        }
        .btn {
            height:44px;
            background:transparent;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        .icon-wrap {
            width:24px;
            height:24px;
        }
        .icon-wrap img {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
       
        * { margin:0; }
        .internet-err-wrap {
            
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .internet-err {
            width:800px;
            
            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;

            
        }
        .internet-err .err-text {
            position:absolute;
            left:5%;
            top:35%;
        }
        .internet-err .err-text h2 {
            font-weight:900;
            font-size: 26px;
            color:#333333;
        }
        .internet-err .err-text > p {
            color:#9FA0A0;
            margin-top:10px;
        }
        .internet-err .err-text button {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin-top:40px;
            font-family:'NanumSquare';
            padding:0 20px;
            
        }
        .internet-err .err-text button .icon-wrap {
            margin-right:5px;
        }
        .internet-err svg {
            width:160%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="internet-err-wrap">
        <div class="internet-err">
            <div class="err-text">
       
                <button class="btn btn-outline-01" onclick="window.location.reload()">
                    <div class="icon-wrap">
                        <img src="/image/icon_replay_b_15pt.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p>retry</p>
                </button>
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here you have written the code only mode of **navigate** but if you want to fetch the image and css from cache then you should use mode as **image** and **style**.
This will allow you to fetch the images and css.

```
 self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {  
      if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
        // Open the cache
        event.respondWith(
          caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
            // Go to the network first
            return fetch(event.request.url)
              .then((fetchedResponse) => {
                cache.put(event.request, fetchedResponse.clone());
    
                return fetchedResponse;
              })
              .catch(() => {
                // If the network is unavailable, get
                // return cache.match(event.request.url);
    
                return cache.match("offline.html");
              });
          })
        );
      } else if (
        event.request.destination === "image" ||
        event.request.destination === "style"
      ) {
        event.respondWith(
          caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
            return cache.match(event.request);
          })
        );
        // return;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
```